# how to test singleton class is creating only one object

Tags: java, singleton

I want to test a singleton class is creating a single object only.
How to test the class.

Here's the code

***Singleton class:-***

```
public class SpringApplicationContext {

    private static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = null;

    private SpringApplicationContext(){};

    public static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext getInstance() {

        if (context == null) {

            context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                    "spring.xml");
        }

        return context;

    }

}
```

***Calling class:-***

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplicationContext.getInstance(); 
    System.out.println("yup");
}
```

Comment: Call `getInstance` multiple times and check if `==` on the references returns true. For composite objects, you will have to check for each reference type inside your singleton.

Comment: Note that your implementation is not thread safe. That is, two threads can cause two instances to be created.

Comment: @TheLostMind - When it will return true. It's returning true only When compared two refferences.

Comment: @RaviKumarRavanam - It will return true if the object being pointed to by the 2 references are the same

Answer (score 1):

You can check with sysout of toString on Object, It prints reference of object, So output of that should be same for all different object.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx1 = SpringApplicationContext.getInstance();
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx2 = SpringApplicationContext.getInstance();

        System.out.println("yup");

        if(System.identityHashCode(ctx1) == System.identityHashCode(ctx2)){

        System.out.println("Hash code is same");

    }
        }
```

Comment: @RaviKumarRavanam - If you really want to use this method, then check for `IdentityHashCode` equality.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. What if the class overrides `toString()` ?

Comment: @RaviKumarRavanam - Check `System.identityHashCode(ctx) == System.identityHashCode(ctx1)`

Comment: @ TheLostMind - Could you please provide sample code with above code where overriding toString method gives different answer.